# regex remove everything not in square brackets

Tags: regex

I have this regular expression that captures what's inside of the square brackets.

```
(?<=(\[req:)).+?(?=(:req]))
```

This grabs all the content inside of [req: and :req]. For example:

`my really cool string [req:do not grab this:req]that I just made`

this takes:

`do not grab this`

However, I want to do the exact opposite. I want to grab everything besides the what's inside [req: and :req] including [req: and :req]. I want to grab:

```
my really cool string that I just made
```

I am sending a screenshot of the words I want to select to make it easier to understand what I am trying to achieve. The ones highlighted in blue is the ones I want to select from `my really cool string [req:do not grab this:req]that I just made`:

[image]

Comment: Replace `\[req:.+?:req]` with an empty string, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/IiGlze/1).

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: I'm trying to grab everything but "grab this." I want to select `my really cool string that I just made` and exclude grab this.

Comment: Are you sure that is the only way? What is the tool/environment where you run the regex?

Comment: still isn't clear where you're using this regex? in code? in shell? which language?

Comment: @gregory most languages have regular expression feature. Even my text editor has regex to find things. I want a solution that is not specific to a feature in a language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention a language, but most that have regex,
enable you to use that in a split function.

Your best bet is to split using a modded version of your current regex:

split( `(?<=\[req:).*?(?=:req\])` )

which will give you all the elements *except* what's between there.

---

The harder way is to match directly *between* the close and open brackets.
Even though this works, its slow and does not take into account
either *balanced* or *nested* brackets (I mean it could, but the regex is really big).

`(?s)(?:^(?:(?!\[req:|:req\]).)*?\[req:|:req\](?:(?!\[req:|:req\]).)*?\[req:|:req\](?:(?!\[req:|:req\]).)*?$)`

https://regex101.com/r/N331qx/1

Readable version:

```
 (?s)                          # Dot-All modifier
 (?:
                                    # Beginning    ...[req:
      ^ 
      (?:
           (?! \[req: | :req\] )
           . 
      )*?
      \[req:
   |                              # or,
                                    # Middle    :req]...[req:
      :req\]
      (?:
           (?! \[req: | :req\] )
           . 
      )*?
      \[req:
   |                              # or,
                                    # End    :req]...
      :req\]
      (?:
           (?! \[req: | :req\] )
           . 
      )*?
      $ 
 )
```

Comment: I thought there would be a easier way to do this.

Comment: @myhouse - My mistake on previous regex. Didn't account for the middle parts between close to open brackets. Acts like _split()_ now. Updated and fixed, and it's an easier and quicker way.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you'll need to capture both sides individually and combine them later on.

`(.*\[req:).*(:req\].*)`

Explanation:

```
(.*\[req:)     | Capture zero or more of any characters followed by "[req:"
.*             | Match zero or more of any characters
(\[req:.*)     | Capture "[req:" followed by zero or more of any characters
```

#### [Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/GPm9ux/2)

Comment: I am trying to select all but what's inside [req: and req\]. In other words, include all but what's inside [req: and req\]

Comment: So include `[req:` and `:req]` but not what's inside?

Comment: yes I added a screenshot on the question with the highlighted characters I want to grab

Comment: Corrected the regex to include those strings.

Comment: your example included the whole string and did not exclude the part I was looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking then. My updated regex captures what you need but matches the whole string.